# Programatically create multiple pages by passing in array of info

Tags: pages

I'm trying to adapt [Tom McFarlin's tutorial on programatically creating a page](http://tommcfarlin.com/programmatically-create-a-post-in-wordpress/) into a function that will create multiple pages by passing in an array of info.  The page gets created in Wordpress, but the page information is all empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. The code is placed in my themes custom functions file.

First, I was passing the array data incorrectly.  Secondly, I was calling the function improperly.  I'm sure there's a way to clean this up, but here's the final code that works.

```
$pages = array(
    $page_onair => array(
        'page_id' => -1,
        'slug' => 'radio-shows',
        'author_id' => 1,
        'title' => 'On Air Shows',
        'tpl' => 'template-onair.php',
    ),
  $page_weather => array(
        'page_id' => -1,
        'slug' => 'weather',
        'author_id' => 1,
        'title' => 'Area Weather',
        'tpl' => 'template-weather.php',
  ),
);
foreach($pages as $pinfo){
    //print_r($pinfo);
    $page_id = $pinfo['page_id'];
    $slug = $pinfo['slug'];
    $author_id = $pinfo['author'];
    $title = $pinfo['title'];
    $tpl = $pinfo['tpl'];

    $pnum += 1;
    $programatically_create_pages = 'programatically_create_pages' + $pnum;
    $programatically_create_pages = function($page_id, $slug, $author_id, $title, $tpl)             {
        $page_id = $page_id;
        $slug = $slug;
        $author_id = $author_id;
        $title = $title;
        $tpl = $tpl;
        //if page doesnt exist create it
        if(null == get_page_by_title($title)){
            //set post id so we know it was successfully created
            $page_id = wp_insert_post(array(
                'comment_status' => 'closed',
                'ping_status' =>'closed',
                'post_author' => $author_id,
                'post_name' => $slug,
                'post_title' => $title,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => 'page',
                )
            );
            update_post_meta($page_id, '_wp_page_template', $tpl);
        } else {
            // use -2 to indicate the page exists
            $post_id = -2;
        }
    };

    add_filter('after_setup_theme', $programatically_create_pages($page_id, $slug,     $author_id, $title, $tpl));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page id's (`$page_id`) in your array are both -1. Have you tried making them unique?

Comment: The values -1, -2 are initially set as defaults and if they are returned, we know that no page was created.

Comment: The code you used in your question shows $page_id = -1 for both items in the array.

Comment: Did you place this code in your theme's functions.php file or in a plugin?

Comment: It's in custom.php (my themes functions file)